# Visual Studio Code - Export source code as HTML formatted

Tags: visual-studio-code, export, save-as

I would like export my source code as html page keeping highlights/styling.

Notedpad++ can export to html. See [this](https://youtu.be/dJ-W3Aua79c) video.
I cannot find it on VS Code.

Any idea?

Comment: There is a `Copy With Syntax Highlighting` command in the Command Palette.  Does that do what you want?  But I don't believe that converts it to an html page.

Comment: I found the release not of this feature:  **Copy with syntax highlighting**
[links](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_copy-with-syntax-highlighting)
But when I copy and paste in a reach text the result is plain text. I searched in the command palette but I don't find it. Please can you try on your device?

Answer (score 0):

I also needed to output HTML in VSCode, so I created an extension that can do that.
For more information, please visit the Visual Studio Marketplace page or the GitHub repository.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Aniny.codetohtml
https://github.com/Aniny21/CodeToHTML

Comment: Thanks , Just installed CopyToHtml ext  it was what I searched for